# Which is the main verb in this simple sentence?

Tags: verbs

> This sentence will automatically tell you that it is written in English Language.

I supposed to use it as an example in my [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/55158/revisions), but after much considerations, I became confused.

I eliminated *will* because it is a modal verb. I also eliminated *tell* because I thought that it was not referring to *this sentence* which is the **subject** and proclaimed *written* as the main verb.

But then, I also thought that *tell* should also be able to be a main verb since it **tells** that *it is written in English language.* In other word, *tells* will have the biggest effect.

Comment: I believe this is one of those cases where the sentence has more than one main verb. (Prevalent in complex sentences)

Comment: This may depend on your teacher, but I think most teachers would say that *will tell* is the main verb. (*[T]hat it is written in English Language [sic]* is not the main clause anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic sentence consists of one subject and one verb, but English sentences can be composed of multiple clauses, each which have their own subject and verb.

In your example there are two clauses junctioned by *that*, which is a common word for this purpose and is often optional and left out:

> This sentence will automatically tell you - that - > it is written in English Language.

So there are two verbs - *tell* and *is*.  *Will* is an auxillary of *tell* and *written* is probably technically something like a complement or "object" of *is*.

Note: The past participle version of a verb will never be the real verb in a sentence or clause, it always requires a form of *to be* or *to have* in front of it.

So which is the "main" verb though?

The phrase *that it is written in English Language* is functioning as an "object" or complement of *tell* - it's answering the question "what is told?"  Not the other way around.  Because of this, that clause is not the main clause in the sentence, so the main verb of the entire sentence is *tell*.